# Firefix/Chromium/Ubuntu Software does not launch on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, software-center, chromium, 22.04

Just got a new pc linux today, first time playing around. I can't open these software, tried reinstalling firefox using --reinstall, tried upgrade, installed chromium from terminal, still doesn't work, also the ubuntu software  does not open. I am not sure what information to send you guys to understand my problem better, and thanks for the help.

Comment: do you get any output when running firefox from terminal? If so, can you paste it here?

Comment: @Esther yes it says "Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. See https://forums.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.

Comment: did you change your home directory? are you running as `root` or something like that?

Comment: what did you change from the default install? Did you choose any unusual options or run any commands *before* noticing that things stopped working? Can you paste output of `echo $HOME`?

Comment: Use terminal to mae sure your system is fully updated: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt full-upgrade` then `sudo snap refresh`.

Comment: @Esther echo $HOME outputs "/home1/grads/ppournas" i am sure there might be some changes because this is my lab pc and is provided by it lab technician.

Comment: @ChanganAuto doing the first command outputs" updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default" i did the others then and it's been told "All snaps are up to date"

Comment: apparently the firefox snap doesn't like that your home directory is under `/home1` not under `/home`. You will have to ask your lab technician what to do about this, and why you don't get a directory under `/home`, and why there are extra ppas added. We don't know what was changed, so we can't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Esther i told my IT Technician. He said he did not changed any default stuff, so he's going to switch to 20.04 LTS. (just for clarifying, in case another issue happened which might be related to 22.04) again thank you all

Comment: he definitely did change *something*, `/home1/grads` is *not* the default home folder in any version of Ubuntu.